# Content Script not loaded on Google Docs, Slides, Sheets, and Forms

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm building a Chrome Extension and everything seems to work fine until my content script stop being loaded on Google Docs, Slides, Sheets, and Forms (it still works on every other website).

I tried to build a new super simple extension from scratch (that just does a console log on every page), and the same issue happens.
The content script of another extension I'm using (1Password) seems to load properly.

I'm not even able to identify when this issue happens (After some time? After something specific happens in the browser?). When I restart my browser everything works again. There's no error in the console and I have absolutely no idea what's happening there.

Here is the code of my super simple extension that has the same issue (happening at the same time):

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Chrome Playground",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["content.js"]
}
```

content.js

```
console.log("Hello");
```

If anyone has any idea where that could come from that'd be very appreciated :D
Thank you so much!

Comment: Open `chrome://policy` and see if those sites are listed in `runtime_blocked_hosts`. If yes, only your network admin can make an exception for you. Otherwise maybe you have installed an offline app for those sites that comes with Chrome by default. If yes, disable or uninstall them.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm ! There's nothing in `runtime_blocked_hosts` but I tried to removed Google Docs offline + all the Google apps. I'll wait and see if that's solving the issue!